# ¿Como añadir un cambio de borde a mi radiobutton?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Quiero es que cuando un `radio button` no esté seleccionado cambie de color su borde a uno rojizo para que se identifique claramente, ya he podido modificar el radio de manera inicial, pero no al aplicarse una acción.

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;

}
input[type="radio"] + span {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 7px;
  padding: 7px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  cursor:pointer;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + span {
  color: #f00;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + span:after {
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75), inset -1px -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  content: " ";
  height: 10px;
  left: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  width: 10px;
}
label:hover input[type="radio"] + span {
  border-color: green;
}
.error_borde {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="left width50">
  <label>Tipo Sistema:</label><font size="4"> * </font><br />
  <label><input type="radio" name="tipoSistemaP" class="radios" id="rbtRadioR" value="1" /><span></span>Remesa</label>
  <label style="float:right;margin-right:80px;"> <input type="radio" name="tipoSistemaP" class="radios" id="rbtRadioPe" value="2" /><span></span>Pedimento Pagado</label>
</div>
```

Código de cambio de borde:

```
$("#rbtRadioR").addClass('error_borde');
```

**Nota:** La accion se debe de ejecutar al darle clic al boton de guardar

Comment: Podrías poner todo (incluyendo el html) en un snippet. De todos modos, ten presente que  `-webkit-appearance: none;` sólo funcionará en Chrome y Safari

Comment: @amenadiel si tambien tenia entendido eso, aunque aun asi me detecta los atributos iniciales, excepto al momento de la accion del boton

Comment: Quieres que al presionar un botón de guardar resalte con borde rojo la opción no seleccionada? O quieres impedir que se envíe el formulario si el usuario no ha elegido al menos una de las dos? Pregunto porque no tiene sentido resaltar algo si vas a guardar el formulario de todas formas.

Comment: @amenadiel  Quieres que al presionar un botón de guardar resalte con borde rojo la opción no seleccionada y se evite el guardar formulario, aunque esa parte ya la realiza

Comment: Pero siempre va a haber al menos una opción no seleccionada. No debiera gatillarse la acción sólo cuando no haya ninguna opción seleccionada?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### El error:

Al aplicar la clase `error_borde`, la regla solo se aplica estilos sobre el `input` y no está modificando el `span`, que es el elemento que tiene el borde azul.

### Solución:

Crear una regla que afecte al `span` hermano adyacente del `input radio` con clase `error_borde`.

```
input[type="radio"].error_borde + span {
  border-color: red;
}
```

### Ejemplo:

```js
function validar() {
  //....
  $("#rbtRadioR").addClass('error_borde');
  //....
}
```

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;

}
input[type="radio"] + span {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-color: blue;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 7px;
  padding: 7px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  cursor:pointer;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + span {
  color: #f00;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + span:after {
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75), inset -1px -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  content: " ";
  height: 10px;
  left: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  width: 10px;
}
label:hover input[type="radio"] + span {
  border-color: green;
}
input[type="radio"].error_borde + span {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left width50">
  <label>Tipo Sistema:</label><font size="4"> * </font><br />
  <label><input type="radio" name="tipoSistemaP" class="radios" id="rbtRadioR" value="1" /><span></span>Remesa</label>
  <label style="float:right;margin-right:80px;"> <input type="radio" name="tipoSistemaP" class="radios" id="rbtRadioPe" value="2" /><span></span>Pedimento Pagado</label>
</div>
<button onclick="validar()">Validar</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

No necesitas usar js para esto. Simplemente dale border-color rojo por defecto, y sobreescribe el color a azul cuando se cumpla la seudopropiedad `:checked`.

Usando tu mismo código (y de nuevo, con la salvedad de que este ejemplo sólo funciona para webkit)

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;

}
input[type="radio"] + span {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 50px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 7px;
  padding: 7px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  cursor:pointer;
  border-color: red;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + span {
  border-color: blue;
}
input[type="radio"]:checked + span:after {
  background: blue;
  border-radius: 50px;
  content: " ";
  height: 10px;
  left: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  width: 10px;
}
label:hover input[type="radio"] + span {
  border-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="left width50">
     <label>Tipo Sistema:</label><font size="4"> * </font><br />
     <label>  
        <input type="radio" name="tipoSistemaP" class="radios" id="rbtRadioR" value="1" />
        <span></span>Remesa
     </label>
     <label style="float:right;margin-right:80px;"> 
         <input type="radio" name="tipoSistemaP" class="radios" id="rbtRadioPe" value="2" />
         <span></span>Pedimento Pagado
      </label>
</div>
```

Comment: gracias @amenadiel solo que talvez no me explique bien en la publicacion, la accion debe de hacerse al darse clic un boton no el mismo radiobutton.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear un radio personalizado a partir de un contenedor que albergue el input y un label que lo referencie. Luego, haciendo uso de `after` puedes simular el punto que indica selección.

> La accion debe de hacerse al darse clic un boton no el mismo radiobutton

Para hacer que el radio sea seleccionado desde un botón solo basta hacer una de dos cosas:

1. Seleccionar al label y ejecutar el evento `click`
2. Seleccionar el input y establecer la propiedad `checked` en `true`.

**Ejemplo**

```js
function select () {
  document.querySelector('#r').checked = true;
  // o
  /*document.querySelector('[for="r"]').click();*/
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.radio {
  display: inline-block;
}

.radio > input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.radio > input[type="radio"] + label {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #bbb;
  border-radius: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  height: 16px;
  transition: background-color .4s ease;
  width: 16px;
}

.radio > input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
  text-align: center;
}

.radio > input[type="radio"] + label:before {
  background-color: #00bbff;
  border-radius: 100%;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 12px;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: scale(5);
  transition: all .3s ease;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 12px;
}

.radio > input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
  visibility: visible;
}

button {
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #555;
  margin-left: 10px;
  padding: 6px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio">
  <input type="radio" id="r">
  <label for="r"></label>
</div>

<button onclick="select()">Seleccionar</button>
```